# Как распарсить yaml с тегами?

Tags: python, yaml

Есть yaml вида:

```yaml
    steps:
  - !<!entry>
    id: Entry-1
    actions: []
  - !<!replybuttons>
    id: ReplyButtons-langcheck
    footer: ''
  - !<!input>
    id: Input-langcheck
    var: Input-1
  - !<!logic>
    id: LangCheck-Logic
    entries:
      - condition: !<!equals>
          var: Input-langcheck
          isCaseSensitive: false
```

Пытаюсь считать его:

```py
import yaml

yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!entry'
```

Как работать с такими тегами в yaml?

Comment: Эм, прочитать документацию?

Comment: Первое, что сделал. Вот не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите <https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/266>

Comment: Попробуйте full_load() <https://death.andgravity.com/yaml-unknown-tag>